# I'm trying to understand how I can use one PHP “master” file to generate individual web pages from multiple text files

Tags: php, html, text-files, static-site

I am building a simple static web site using PHP includes. Right now I have a basic page structure that looks something like this…

*Insert header and footer, and set page title:*

```
<?php
require_once("inc/class.page.php");
$page = new page("My Page Title");
?>
```

*Top hero:*

```
<?php include("inc/tophero.php"); ?>
```

*Left sidebar:*

```
<?php include("inc/sideleft.php"); ?>
```

*Get page content from text file:*

```
<?php include("content/file-with-text-and-html-inside.txt"); ?>
```

What I'm trying to discover is if there is a way to just use a single page-structure PHP file (such as `mynewpage.php`) that can generate a unique HTML page for each text file located in a `content` directory.

So for instance, say there is a `my-brand-new-blog-post.txt` file in the content directory, my goal to generate an HTML file at the following URL: `https://example.org/my-brand-new-blog-post.php`

As I write this question I'm having doubts about whether I'm conceptualizing this correctly, but am unsure of how else to frame this question. My main objective is to keep my content files and PHP code as separate as possible. I'd prefer the content files to contain only text and minimal HTML markup.

My goal in having a universal page structure PHP file (`mynewpage.php`) is so I have only one page-structure file to update when I want to update how I use PHP within my site, rather than having to go into each content text file to update PHP code.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a CMS?

Comment: @FluffyKitten: You're basically correct. I'm actually just trying to construct a very basic, bare-bones CMS with next to no bells and whistles.

Comment: Well at the very minimum you're doing to need a database or file system to store the content for each page, but that is too broad (and opinionated :) ) for a question on Stack Overflow. But there are already lightweight CMSs out there that offer this and more (including versions, etc) so I'd suggest looking into that rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you, @FluffyKitten. I'm absolutely trying to avoid using a database, mainly because my experience with using Drupal, MediaWiki, WordPress, etc on my cheap shared hosting account has been to lose precious years of my life watching pages slowly load. More seriously, I anticipate this particular site I'm building will probably never grow beyond a few dozen pages. But to your point, is there a lightweight flat-file CMS you can recommend?

Comment: Afraid not. I've tried a lot of CMSs (existing, now-defunct & custom-built) over 15-odd years, but now I go for DB-driven systems for their maintainability, version control (a *must* if other users can update the site), etc. I'd avoid custom-build mainly because of the user interface - the system itself can be trivial, the complexity comes in building the UI with authorisation, security, editing facilities, validation, error-checking, rollbacks, image handling, file uploads, styling etc. FYI I've created small & mid-size Wordpress sites on standard shared hosting without issue if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are really just spitting out text(or html) in a php-generated container, you are pretty much on the right track. BUT as soon as you have dynamic content i highly support FluffyKittens advice to get your hands on a CMS of your choice.

Nevertheless here are some shortcuts to acheive what you want.

I assume you are using an apache-server. You can implement a [rewrite-rule](https://gist.github.com/RaVbaker/2254618), which redirects request to a single `index.php`. If you are using nginx, you will be able to do the same, just ask google :)

Your rewrite-rule would look like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]`

#### `index.php`

```
<?php
    
$rawContentToLoad = $_GET['q'];
$contentToLoad = preg_replace('/[^a-z-]/', '', $rawContentToLoad ); // sanitize

include('header.php');

// ...

// you may want to check if the file actually exists and return a default 404 page in case it doesnt. "is_file" is the function you can use for this.
include('content/' . $contentToLoad . '.html'); // i suggest html instead of txt here

// ...

include('footer.php');
```

To get an individual title (and possibly other metadata) i suggest a json file for each file in `content/`. Will be read in `header.php`.

Do not skip the sanitize. It will accept only `a-z` and `-`, or you will be vulnerable to [path-traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal).

#### `example .htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Pilan. Indeed, I wouldn't even have posted the question if I were intending to generate dynamic content; would have just stuck with Drupal or WordPress. For this particular site I'm just working with simple, static pages. I'll have the chance to test out your idea in the next day or so, and will give a report-back.

Comment: I'm just not getting your code to work. I'm not sure if my `.htaccess` file has a conflict after the inclusion of yet another rewrite rule, or if I just don't understand your code, or if the issue is something else I'm not even thinking of. The end result is my site doesn't load, and the URL is formatted like this: `https://www.example.org//` (with two trailing slashes).

Comment: Delete what ever rewrite rule you have and add to one i added. - Which part of my code dont you understand? Its just some includes and a [preg_repalce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) which removes everything which is not `a-z` or a `-` of `$rawContentToLoad` and saves it in `$contentToLoad`. I just noticed i forgot to rename a variable in there. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, @Pilan. When I placed your code in a clean directory, and used only the example `.htaccess` conditions and rules you suggested in your answer, I was able to get the page to load. For the content file, I used a file literally named “`Content To Load.html`” containing only this: `<p>Body Content</p>`. The page loaded, but only as an index page, not as a URL like “`content-to-load.html`”. This wasn’t the direction I had attempted to describe above, so I will try to rethink my question so it comes across more clearly.

Comment: @DavidJ.Myers You want `example.com/bla.php` to load index.php which loads header footer etc and `content/bla.txt`. This is exactly what my solution does. The name is getting sanitized. It must contain of `a-z` and `-` no spaces, no dots, no slashes or anything. - There is some basic you are missing. List all what you have in yor question, each content of file and its location. Your webserver and what urls you are exactly testing.

Comment: I'm not sure you and I are communicating well. Of course I understand that the proper way to name a web file is without spaces, capital letters, or any other illegal characters. I had understood you to say that even if the file was improperly named, your script would fix it; and indeed the file formatted as `Content To Load.html` loaded.

Comment: But even after I renamed the file from `Content To Load.html` to the more proper `content-to-load.html`, the file will not load at the full URL (e.g. `https://example.org/content-to-load.html`). That URL *does* display the header and footer, just not the body content. However, if I simply go to `https://example.org` the body text inside the `content-to-load.html` file actually loads, just like it did when it was improperly formatted as `Content To Load.html`. All I'm trying to say is that this, while interesting, is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DavidJ.Myers Again: Post your .htaccess and your code in your question. Or even better. Learn how to use [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: try the url `example.com/test` and name your file `test.html`

Comment: — I posted facsimiles of my `.htaccess`, `class.page.php` and other includes, and `index.php` code here:
`https://docs.google.com/document/u/2/d/e/2PACX-1vREwKbRA0ZKM-RiiJuPUZkTZMgWIW9sZBe0oE6HHX7JkdRw_R6ZaMLs-lcK9D2ahP_xQPdwnwBvSCVx/pub`

Comment: Neither your `.htaccess` nor your `index.php` looks even remotely close to what i've suggested. The fact that you have a `RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1/ [R=301,L]` in there speaks for itself. Empty the whole file. Add my code - try to understand it, then add whatever you need line by line and again try to understand it. Im done here.

Comment: I posted what is working for me now, not what you suggested. The code you suggested that I use doesn't work for me. I used it like you wrote it.